# Bound on the treewidth of a graph from modular contraction

Tags: reference-request, graph-theory, treewidth

I cannot find a reference for this easy to prove result concerning the treewidth of a graph with respect to the treewidth of a modular contraction of it.

Let $G=(V,E)$ be a graph. A module $M \subseteq V$ is a set such that for every $u,v \in M$, $N(u) \setminus M = N(v) \setminus M$ where $N(u)$ is the neighborhood of $u$. We denote by $N(M) = N(u) \setminus M$ for some $u \in M$.

Let $\mathcal{M}=\{M_1, \dots, M_k\}$ be a partition of $V$ into modules (possibly of size $1$).  The contraction $G/\mathcal{M}$ of $G$ with respect to $\mathcal{M}$ is defined as:

- the vertex set of $G/\mathcal{M}$ is $\mathcal{M}$,
- There is an edge $\{M,M'\}$ in $G/\mathcal{M}$ if and only if $N(M) \cap M' \neq \emptyset$. Observe that in this case, $M' \subseteq N(M)$ and $M \subseteq N(M')$.

One can easily construct a class of graph such that for every graph $G$ in this class, there exists a parition $\mathcal{M}$ of $V$ into modules such that the treewidth of $G/\mathcal{M}$ is $1$ but $G$ has unbounded treewidth (take the class of cliques for example). However, one needs to contract large modules if one wants it to happen. This is due to the following fact:

**Lemma**: Let $\mathcal{M}=\{M_1,\dots,M_k\}$ be a parition of $V$ into modules. Then $tw(G) \leq m \cdot (1+tw(G/\mathcal{M}))$ where $m = \max{|M_i|}$.

The proof of this lemma is not too hard to handwave but as usual, formalizing it is a bit of pain. Basically, replacing every occurrence of $M_i$ in a tree decomposition for $G/\mathcal{M}$ by the vertices in $M_i$ gives a tree decomposition for $G$ with the desired properties.

However, I have failed to find any reference where this has been stated and proven. That is why I am asking for your help! Bonus point if someone also has a reference where a similar bound is also proven for clique-width (I expect this bound to be independent on $m$ for clique-width however; contracting large modules should not change clique-width much!).